# Work done in extending a wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, work

> A mass of 0.5 kg is suspended from wire, then length of wire increase by 3 mm then find out work done

I thought work would be given as $\int F_{ext} \cdot dx$, giving $mg \Delta h=(.5) g (3\times 10^{-3})$, but apparently it is $ \frac{mg \Delta h}{2}$.

The solution arrives at this by considering $W= \frac{yAl}{L} \frac{l}{2}$, which is the energy associated with Young's modulus and using a force balance in the final state to achieve $Mg = \frac{yAl}{L}$, reducing the work to

$$ W= \frac12 FL.$$

This means that in total, only half of the gravitational work is done on the wire... but where did the other half go?

Comment: Work done by what? The force doing the work needs to be specified.

Comment: The question was framed this way when I got it, I assumed that external forces would be the one which does @BioPhysicist

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is ambiguous. If one applies a constant force to the end of the wire, causing the end to oscillate around and ultimately settle down to the new equilibrium length via damping, then the work done by the force is $mg\Delta h$—it's just that half of that went into strain energy in the wire and half was dissipated as heat. When it comes to non-state variables such as work and heat, it's often essential to articulate the process clearly (e.g., "What is the work done by the weight on the wire?" or "What is the work done by the weight that is lost as heat?") or alternatively to use state variables (e.g., "What is the increase in strain energy of the wire?" or "What is the energy increase in the surrounding environment?").

Answer (score 0):

The force is not constant along the way, it increases with the distance. you can consider the wire like a strong spring. can you calculate the work if F=k*x.(it is easy to elongate for 0.1mm it is hard  from 2,9mm to 3mm)

Comment: As Chemomechanics states, the system will first oscillate (SHO), then damping will cause the mass to eventually settle at a new equilibrium point.